# Setting a row limit for python code within for loop?

Tags: python, tkinter

*Question:* How would I alter a `Tkinter.Label`'s row once a certain number of rows have been reached within the `for` loop?

*Code:*

```
import Tkinter
import sys
from fractions import gcd


def func(event):
    x = int(e1.get())  # get max number
    result = []
    for a in range(1, x):  # loops to get each value in range of x
        for b in range(a, x):
            for c in range(b, x):
                if a**2 + b**2 == c**2 and gcd(a, b) == 1:  # if it is a primitive pyth triple, append result
                    result += ['[',a,',',b,',',c,']']  # add group of triples to list
    l = Tkinter.Message(root, text=result).grid(ipadx=5, ipady=5, sticky='W''E')  # display each group of triples to root
    l0 = Tkinter.Label(root, text="Non-primitive and primitive triples").grid(ipadx=5, ipady=5, sticky='W''E')
    root.bind('<Return>', close)  # Hit enter to exit, only temp for debugging, will reassign to button later


def close(event):  # close program, define parameter event to allow for binding
    Tkinter.sys.exit(0)
    sys.exit(0)


root = Tkinter.Tk()  # establish main gui
root.title('Generator')
e1 = Tkinter.Entry(root)
assert isinstance(e1, object)  # only method I've found to allow for Entry().grid()
e1.grid(ipadx=5, ipady=5, sticky='W''E')
root.bind('<Return>', func)  # bind to Enter, cleaner and quicker than a button
root.mainloop()
```

So, if I have a window that displays

[#,#,#]

[#,#,#]

[#,#,#]

[#,#,#]

*how would I change that to, if I want the row limit to be four(starting on the second row in the first column because of an entry widget, so second column would have one more than the first column, and remain constant for each successive column), this:*

*entry*.....[#,#,#]

[#,#,#]....[#,#,#]

[#,#,#]....[#,#,#]

[#,#,#]....[#,#,#]

I'm wanting the `l = Tkinter.Message(root, text=result).grid(ipadx=5, ipady=5, sticky='W''E')  # display each group of triples to root` to be in the `for` loop's `if` statement, and to change it to `l = Tkinter.Label(root, text=('[',a,',',b,',',c,']')).grid(ipadx=5, ipady=5, sticky='W''E')  # display each group of triples to root`

*UPDATE*

I fixed the code with this code thanks to some help on here:

```
import Tkinter
import sys
from fractions import gcd


def func(event):
    x = int(e1.get())  # get max number
    row = 0
    column = 0
    count = 0
    for a in range(1, x):  # loops to get each value in range of x
        for b in range(a, x):
            for c in range(b, x):
                if a**2 + b**2 == c**2 and gcd(a, b) == 1:  # if it is a primitive pyth triple, print
                    row += 1
                    l = Tkinter.Label(root, text=('[',a,',',b,',',c,']'))
                    assert isinstance(l, object)
                    l.grid(row=row, column=column, ipadx=5, ipady=5, sticky='W''E')  # display each group of triples to root
                    root.title('Primitive Triples')
                    if count > 1:
                        l.destroy()
                    if row == 7:
                        column += 1
                        row -= 8


def close():  # close program
    Tkinter.sys.exit(0)
    sys.exit(0)


root = Tkinter.Tk()  # establish main gui
root.title('Generator')
e1 = Tkinter.Entry(root)
assert isinstance(e1, object)  # only method I've found to allow for Entry().grid()
e1.grid(ipadx=5, ipady=5, sticky='W''E')
root.bind('<Return>', func)  # bind to Enter, cleaner and quicker than a button
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just grid the entry in row 0, column 0, the first button in row 0, column 1, the second button in row 1, column 0, etc.  What's the problem?

Comment: I'm wanting the label to be shifted into the for loop and it displays each individual triple, not the entire list so It's all jumbled together

Comment: I don't understand.  Can you give a concrete example?

Comment: I'm wanting the `for` loop to edit root with a `Tkinter.Label` each time it runs through the loop, so, instead of [#,#,#][#,#,#][#,#,#][#,#,#][#,#,#][#,#,#][#,#,#][#,#,#][#,#,#][#,#,#], you'll get a nice, simple layout, of each pyth triple in a clean row and column

Comment: How would I set the grid for an undetermined amount of triples while still in a for loop, and it isn't a button, it's one Label being updated with new values and being added to root, there aren't several Labels, it's one. If you indent the `Message` , and change it to `Label` and input '50' then I think you'll understand what I'm asking

Comment: You have two variables row and column that indicate where the next item is to be gridded.  You use `widget.grid(row=row, column=column)`.  Then you increment column.  If column == 2, set it back to 0, and increment row.

Comment: Ah, I was think grid has to have only integers, not any variables, but that worked great man